# Alternative to pass by reference in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a c++ programmer learning javascript.

I have a javascript function *loadTexture* to load an image from a URL and create an opengl texture from it. It works asynchronously and returns a *Promise* object so that I can tell when it's finished. All good :)

But I'd like to be able to tell it where to store the resulting opengl texture id, something like this -

```
var catImageFuture = loadTexture("cat.png", this.catTextureId);
/* Wait for the future, and several other ones to complete before doing the next thing */
```

And have it store the opengl id it generates in the variable I passed in as the second parameters. In C++ this would be simple, I could pass a reference or a pointer to the variable to the function. But this isn't possible in Javascript as it has no pass by reference or pointers.

What is the right way to achieve a similar aim in Javascript.

Comment: Yes, I load it with that and then in the onload handler make an opengl texture and complete the Promise object

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript has no mechanism (yet) to elegantly inline asynchronous code. Right now, everything is done with callbacks. If you implement a `done` method on your `Future` object that passes its result as an argument to a callback, you'd be able to write:

```
var that = this; // You may need this, depending on how you implement Future.done

loadTexture("cat.png").done(function(result) {
    that.catTextureId = result;
});
```

JavaScript runtimes will support generators in a few years, so you'll soon be writing:

```
this.catTextureId = yield loadTexture("cat.png");
```

Comment: Right, thank you.
The first thing was what I was hoping to avoid, it's a bit ugly when you want to load 30 textures. But if I need to , then I need to :)

Comment: @jcoder: Can you post the rest of your code (or at least what you do with the 30 textures)? I'm sure there's a nicer way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you would use a function. The function would receive the data as a parameter and store it wherever is appropriate. You might use a closure to capture a reference to a local variable.

Another option is to always wrap the data in an object. Pass the object to your function, and ithe function can assign a property of the object. Objects and arrays are passed like pointers in Javascript, so when the function modifies it, it will be visible to the caller.

Comment: This would mean that I'd have to write a new function to capture and store the value for every single call to loadTexture though to store the id in the appropriate variable. I know it's mostly just typing, but it does seem very elegant.

Comment: Maybe you can refactor what you're doing so you do it with one or two functions, or define a class to encapsulate it.

Comment: I can think of a few things I can do. None of which I particularly like. Your answer is good, even if it's not the answer I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways:

You can use custom object and manage that, like:

```
var cat = new Cat();
cat.texture = new Texture();
...
```

Or you can use callbacks:

```
var TextureId;

function loadTexture(path, callback)
{
    var img = new Image(path);
    var id = (GetSomeHowId);\
    img.onload = (function(i){ return (function(){callback(i);}); })(id);
}

loadTexture("cat.png", (function(id){ TextureId = id; }));
```

Hope you got the point.